# How to delete blank columns in one go in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

How can I delete blank columns in one go in LibreOffice Calc? I searched online but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: @muclux Libreoffice is installed in Ubuntu by default. Questions about using it are on-topic

Answer (score 1):

**@Mahipal Gunawat wrote:**

> I'm myself giving the answer.
>
> 1. Select first row or any other row (whether the column will be considered blank or not will be based on the cells of the row you select.)
> 2. Open the find and replace window. (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
> 3. Write something in *Replace* text box then *Find All* will become clickable. Click this button.
> 4. *Search results* windows will pop up. Close this window.
> 5. Close *Find & Replace* window. Be cautious; don't click anywhere else in spreadsheet.
> 6. Click on cell of any blank column that has been already selected in step 3.
> 7. Do right click. A pop up window will appear. Select *Delete...*; another pop up window will appear. Select radio button for *Delete Entire Column(s)* and click.

Comment: OK, thanks. It's considered nicer to 1. comment on the question suggesting the user move their answer to an answer themselves so they can get credit for it, 2. if the comment gets no response, edit the question and write a *community wiki* answer and 3. blockquote the OP's answer to highlight the fact that it's not your own work

Comment: @Zanna: Okay, I'll keep those things in mind in the future.  This community is rather more friendly and polite than others I've encountered.  :)